# Trying to use a TreeMap in a subclass entitiy

Tags: dictionary, subclass, treemap, joined-subclass

I have found help for subclassing of a mapped superclass, and I have found help on how to map a TreeMap.   However, I can not find anything that covers using a TreeMap in a subclass at all.  Here is the situation:    I am adding a function to a long-existing application.  That application has mapped entities, a certain set of which, form a hierarchy.   There is a , for instance that establishes the base class.  Then there are many many MANY subclasses that use the  elements to map the individual subclasses.  The subclasses all use  elements to reference the additional table that holds the attributes of the subclass.  This has worked for several years and life has seemingly been good.

Now along comes my work effort and I need to use a TreeMap in my new subclass entity (extending the same base class as all of the others) so the first thing that I do is attempt to map it the same way other subclasses do,  with a  inside a .

Making the story short, I got an error when I started the app and Hibernate began mapping.  Researching this error led me to review the DTD for hibernate mapping files and, guess what?  According to my interpretation, one can not configure a Map of any kind inside a .

That same research exposed me to the  which CAN contain a Map.   So, off I go configuring a  inside the base class mapping.

When I did this, I got bizarre errors referencing symbols that I can't even find in the code, in mappings.... anywhere!   More research and I find a reference in the Hibernate reference manual, Chapter 9, that says that Hibernate does not support mixing of  and  elements.  So that can't be done either.

My question is:  is there a solution that I have missed along the way?  From the sound of things it seems that you can NOT configure a map in a subclass if you are using  because the  inside it won't take a map....     and, while a Map can be configured in a , I doubt that I can gather up much support around here for wading through the current mapping files and re-mapping ALL  entities as  entities.

Has anybody got any ideas? If I am not looking at this right, believe me, I am willing to accept that and learn!

Comment: Many languages have a `TreeMap` are you using Java? or...?